# Running only one zone of a multi zone minisplit

Tags: air-conditioning

I picked up a used multi zone mini-split (Yeti YEOD24000, they don't make them anymore, I think they were actually produced by Gree).

The guy I bought it from was running two zones before, I have no idea what length the linesets were.  It was disconnected by an HVAC tech so I'm assuming there is refrigerant in there.  I have the outdoor unit installed along with one of the indoor units.

My question is, can I operate the one unit by itself, without having the other unit installed (*the valve is closed on the other zone*)?  I will, of course, vacuum the lines first.

Again, I'm not sure of the volume of refrigerant in the system, probably less than the spec as the unit is old.

Comment: "release the refrigerant" That would be a HELL TO THE NO!!!! NEVER release refrigerant to the atmosphere!!! It destroys it. That it why to do any work on a system that contains refrigerant... You need a certification from the EPA. One of the reasons work on a HVAC system is not A DIY project.

Comment: I modified my original post to make it clearer: releasing the refrigerant into the lines not into the atmosphere.

Comment: Why assume it contains refrigerant? The tech could have (properly) emptied the system before disconnection. Any caps on the pipes / fittings could be just to stop bugs, dirt etc from entering.

Comment: Guy who sold it to me said it has refrigerant in it.

Comment: Wait, does this thing use R-22 or one of the newer 3-digit R's?  *If it uses R-22, you don't want it*... #1 they just stopped making R-22 (really) which means the cost is going ballistic. #2 random handymen can't work on HVAC because of the recovery requirements - it's already necessary to use a vacuum for the system to work, the requirement is to capture the old refrigerant and take it in to a licensed recycler for re-refinement or annihilation.  At this point, recycling is the only possible source of R-22.   And yeah, people venting R-22 is basically why we have to use sunblock.

Comment: Refrigerant is R410A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would not be posting about violating the law on a public forum. (EPA fines up to 25k for violating the 608 & 609 regulations)
Yes it is normal to close the high pressure line and pump the refrigerant into the system and close the low pressure valve prior to putting a recovery system on the lines.
A licensed tech can still purchase R22 online the price has really jumped the last few years and will increase until the supply is exhausted no more can be made or imported.
Can a multi zone system function with only 1 zone attached? Possibly , some can some must be connected or at least have a loop it depends on the design.
You understand the system needs to have a vacuum on the line set epa recommends 500 millitor most techs target under 100 and verify no leakage.
Who knows if the system has enough refrigerant to run, most folks do not remove fully functional systems so it is quite possible you only have a couple of lbs when it is a 6 or 8 lb system.

Comment: Unit is not in the US and refrigerant is R410A

Comment: Well r410 is a high pressure gas the service life on high pressure compressors has been much shorter than r12 & r22.  I did try to look up that model and found nothing that’s why. Guessed on the r22.  But the answer would be the same some can and some cannot be used unless a loop is installed.